# Kähler differentials, smooth algebras (one specific question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative algebra (of essentially finite type, perhaps I have to add other reasonable assumptions) over a field, and I assume that $\Omega^1(A)$ is a projective module. Then the definition of $\Omega^1$ gives the following exact sequence of bimodules
$$
0 \to I^2 \to I \to \Omega^1 \to 0,
$$
where $I$ is the kernel of multiplication homomorphism $A \otimes A \to A$. Module $\Omega^1$ is projective, thus, if we consider the sequence as sequence of (for example) left modules, sequence splits
$$
s: \Omega^1 \to I.
$$
Splitting $s$ induces a map of bimodules
$$
A \otimes \Omega^1 \to I.
$$
In one paper I found a claim that the last map is surjective, but I can't see why it is surjective. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you be more clear in the definition of that last map?

Comment: Decomposable elements $b \otimes x$  go to $s(x) (1 \otimes b)$.